# Помогите решить задачу в SQL оператор JOIN

Tags: sql

Не могу отобразить максимальную зарплату работников.

Вот само задание:
Даны таблицы department и employee.
Отобразите название отделов и максимальную зарплату работников, работающих там.
Результат должен содержать следующие колонки:
-название отдела: department_name
-максимальную зарплату: max_salary
Примечания:
-не забудьте сгруппировать результаты по одному из столбцов из вашего SELECT
-эту задачу можно выполнить, не используя сортировку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:
SELECT name AS department_name, salary AS max_salary
FROM department
INNER JOIN employee
ON department.id = employee.department_id
WHERE hiring_date is NOT NULL

Comment: Ну русским же по белому написано: **не забудьте сгруппировать результаты по одному из столбцов из вашего SELECT** !!! Где?

Comment: Когда пытаюсь сгруппировать выдает ошибку

Comment: ТС написал в ответе, который был (будет) удалён: _Всем спасибо! Сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос_.

Comment: я правильно понял, в поле "ответ" я должен написать решение задачи?

Comment: @Serhii Да, вы поняли правильно.

Comment: Спасибо что поправили.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name AS department_name, MAX (salary) AS max_salary  
FROM department  
INNER JOIN employee  
ON department.id = employee.department_id  
WHERE hiring_date is NOT NULL  
GROUP BY name
```